# Is Passing a result set in java possible?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to make a command where i can send different queries to a SQLite / Mysql DB and return the resultset to whatever function is calling. It needs to be able to process whether there is 2 columns or 15.

The below doesn't work - presumably because it closes the resultset / connection but I'm not sure how else to do it.

Thoughts?

```
public static ResultSet queryDB(String query) {
    try {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + Settings.SQLITE_DB_PATH);
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
        resultSet.close();
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
        return resultSet;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SQLInterp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You can pass it so long as you don't close it, or its respective `Statement`/`Connection`, before attempting to read from it.

Comment: Jacob G - Wouldn't that cause a memory leak?

Comment: Assuming you close it after using it, no.

Comment: How do you close it if you return the results prior to closing ?

Comment: how have you obtained the `ResultSet` from `statement` - so it must be possible to pass one in Java (asnwer to title)

Comment: Carlos - statement.executeQuery(query);

Comment: @DotSlashShell One option is to not return the `ResultSet`, but rather pass in a `Consumer<ResultSet>` as a parameter that you accept with the `ResultSet` itself.

Comment: You just need to think about which class should have the responsibility of closing the ResultSet after you've finished using it.

Comment: @JacobG. Could you give me an example? I've never used those.

Comment: 1) exactly, so if `statement.executeQuery` is able to return one, so can your method; 2) can be bad practice since *shraing* the responsibility, that is, one method is *creating* the `ResultSet`, the other is (hopefully) closing it - can't you return a Collection (e.g. List) with  the results

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger - The problem is the results are never the same. some are 2 columns some 19 - Although Thinking about it now maybe I can just return a list.

Comment: No point in converting a ResultSet to a List, if you're not using any List-specific functionality.  Jacob's `Consumer<ResultSet>` idea is the right way to go.

Comment: that's why I wrote that it **can** be bad practice, then just return the `ResultSet` and write on the documentation that the receiver must close it... or, better IMO, solution proposed by Jacob - using a `Consumer` (function) that will *consume* the `ResultSet`

Comment: I've no idea what a Consumer<ResultSet> so I'm going to start researching.

Comment: functional programing, in essence kind of a method that will be called getting the `ResultSet` as parameter (like a call back method, somehow similar to a listener)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically have 3 choices:

1. Don't close the `ResultSet`, `Statement`, and `Connection` in the method, handing off responsibility for doing that back to the caller.

   **Not recommended**, since it is error-prone, and breaks well-formed code structure paradigms.
2. Pass in an object with the logic that is needed for processing the data, as [suggested by Jacob G.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55911792/is-passing-a-result-set-in-java-possible#comment98478494_55911792).

   E.g. use a Java 8+ [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html):

   ```
   public static void queryDB(String query, Consumer<ResultSet> processor) {
       try (
           Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + Settings.SQLITE_DB_PATH);
           Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
           ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
       ) {
           processor.accept(resultSet);
       } catch (SQLException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(SQLInterp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
   }
   ```

   Then call it like this:

   ```
   SQLInterp.queryDB("SELECT * FROM foo", rs -> {
       while (rs.next()) {
           // process data here
       }
   });
   ```
3. Read all the data into memory in a generic data structure, e.g. `List<Map<String, Object>>`:

   This of course assumes that query has good unique names for each column.

   ```
   public static List<Map<String, Object>> queryDB2(String query) {
       try (
           Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + Settings.SQLITE_DB_PATH);
           Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
           ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
       ) {
           ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
           int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
           String[] name = new String[columnCount];
           for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
               name[i] = metaData.getColumnLabel(i + 1);
           List<Map<String, Object>> rows = new ArrayList<>();
           while (resultSet.next()) {
               Map<String, Object> row = new LinkedHashMap<>();
               for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
                   row.put(name[i], resultSet.getObject(i + 1));
               rows.add(row);
           }
           return rows;
       } catch (SQLException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(SQLInterp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I opted for #2 and will be trying it now. However how does the connection close ?

Comment: @DotSlashShell The code is using [try-with-resources](https://www.google.com/search?q=try-with-resources), a feature added in Java 7.

Comment: Thanks ! It worked. Could you elaborate about the try-with-resources? I don't see anything different in #2 that would say its trying with resources or closing the connection?

Comment: @DotSlashShell Did you follow the link I provided and e.g. look at the [The Java™ Tutorials - The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) article in the search list?